# Shell Script to read output of command

Tags: shell, scripting, http

I'm doing a script to monitor some things from websites and one of the things is to monitor the http status and their response time.

In the script I run a command to get the http_status:
(http command is provided by: httpie : A Curl-like tool for humans)

```
http -timeout 10 -follow -h http: //$I/ | grep "HTTP\/1.1" | awk '{print $2}'
```

This command will return the status itself, ie: 200, 404, 403, etc. or will return two other things:

```
http: error: Request timed out (10.0s)
```

or

```
http: error: ConnectionError ..."
```

Note: Increasing the timeout does not solve my problem. I need it to be 10 seconds.

How do I put a specific code when returning these two other options? For example in the timeout return `9999` and error `8888`.

Comment: Just to know, I want the returned status to be the site itself (200,302, 403, etc) and in case of error return some number so that through a dashboard can mount the status of all my sites.

So would have the:
Site xxx.com = status 200
Site xyx.org = status 900
etc

Answer (score 0):

A simple `case` statement should do what you want:

```
case "$(http_status)" in
    "case 1")
        return 199
        ;;
    "case 2")
        return 198
        ;;
    *)
        # All is well; do nothing
        ;;
esac
```

You can use wildcards, e. g. `*"timed out"*)` or `*"ConnectionError"*)`.

Comment: what i do wrong? (forced a wrong url)

    http_code=$(http --timeout 10 --follow -h http://wwwwww.google.com.br | grep "HTTP\/1.1" | awk '{print $2}')


case "($http_code)" in
        *"timed out"*)
                return 8888
                echo 8888
                ;;
        *"ConnectionError"*)
                return 9999
                echo 9999
                ;;
        *)
                echo $http_code
                ;;
esac
~

Comment: Return codes cannot AFAIK be higher than 255.

Comment: Changed return code to 8 and 9 respectively. but script cant get the status returned by programm.